# Find $y'$ where $y=\ln(x+\sqrt{a^2+x^2}).$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-verification

## My solution

Of course, you may apply the derivative rule for the compound function. But I want to give another solution with little computation.

Denote
$$u=x+\sqrt{a^2+x^2},$$
$$v=x-\sqrt{a^2+x^2}.$$
Then
$$u+v=2x,uv=-a^2.$$
Hence
$$u'+v'=2,u'v+uv'=0.$$
We may obtain
$$\frac{u'}{u}=\frac{2}{u-v}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}.$$
As a result
$$y'=\frac{u'}{u}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}.$$

**AM I RIGHT?**

Comment: Well your proof seems correct. However I don't see why it's such a big deal. Using chain rule would have been shorter.

Comment: For derivatives it indeed seems a bit unnecessary, but this is a good technique. For example, the **anti**-derivative of secant (the trig $\frac1{ \cos}$) can be obtained in a similar fashion that is much more elegant than some of the other methods.